# Moving global resources to custom folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resources

I have an ASP.NET MVC2 application where I need to support not only multiple languages, but also potentially multiple versions of each language. I usually solve localization requirements by using resx files in the App_GlobalResources folder, and this works well as long as I do not need to support multiple resource-sets for the same language.

This is an issue because each customer shall be able to specify a set of resources, and they may use the same language.

My initial thought was to have a file structure where every customer has a separate folder located under for instance App_Data. In this customer folder I would put configuration files and resources. But then I would need a way to tell the application that it should look for resources in this particular folder instead of App_GlobalResources.

So my question is: Is this doable, and what do I have to do to make it work? Is this a bad way to solve a problem like this, and if that seems to be the case: Does anyone have suggestions for a better solution?

Will be thankful for all input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use a custom [ResourceProviderFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.resourceproviderfactory.aspx) to store the resources in the database. Creating a custom provider to look in specific folders should not be to hard if you can distinguish the different customers by virtualpath.

Comment: I think that is a good solution! Will try it out, and come back when it is tested! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> But then I would need a way to tell the application that it should look for
>   resources in this particular folder instead of App_GlobalResources.

You might consider compiling your resources so that they are deployed as DLLs rather than compiled at runtime. To do this you have to move your resources our of the standard App_GlobalResources.

This post has a good explanation of the benefits of doing this:

http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx